# First time after render props are passed they are undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hey I found this nice way to check width of device, I implemented it in my code to make page be more responsive.

```
const [width, setwidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const handleResize = () => {
    setwidth(window.innerWidth);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
  });
```

I have three components

- Header

  - Main

    - Footer

I pass `width` to child components as props (from `Header`), on render all values are fine (It actually shows `1879` which is width of window on 110% zoom but It's better than `undefined`). It is how I pass props to child components

```
const [width, setwidth] = useState(props.width);
  useEffect(() => {
    setwidth(props.width);
  }, [props.width]);
```

Here is part of `Footer` that decides on classname (for responsivity purposes)

```
className={width > 1080 ? "footer" : "footer-vertical"}
```

`Footer` renders `className="footer-vertical"` even though width in console on render shows `1879` and then after first zoom in `Main` recieves correct value which is `1879` but `Footer` recieves `undefined`. It also happens when i reset window zoom with built in button, besides that it works as intended. Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: Your useEffect for event listener has to be:   useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

Comment: @OktayYuzcan That helped with initial wrong value  now it shows `2087` on render but rest is still wrong, thank you anyway

Comment: Okay I found problem I was updating `width` in another `useEffect`